# R - Check if a range of dates contains a certain value, using dates from a different data frame

Tags: r, date, for-loop, twitter, lubridate

I'm working on a project analyzing Credit Card companies' rate changes over time and tweets from common credit card companies over the same time period. Goal is to see if we can predict when a credit card company is going to change rates based on their Twitter accounts.

I have two data frames: 1) if the interest rate changed on a given date [RATES] and 2) tweets and what day they were created [TWEETS]. For every date in TWEETS, I want to filter the RATES Data set on essentially TWEETS$DATE_CREATED - 7 to TWEETS$DATE_CREATED and see if there was a rate change in the RATES dataset in this date range.

Right now, I'm using a for loop to do this (ugh, I know). It's incredibly slow and I'm sure this is a way to do this for loop in a one-liner which performs faster. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This for-loop filters RATES down to each of the TWEETS$created_date and the previous 7 days and looks for a 1 in the TWEETS$changedToday column, then puts it in a new column in Tweets.

```
install.packages("lubridate") #dates modification package
library(lubridate)

rates.date <- mdy(c("01/01/20", "01/02/20", "01/03/20", "01/04/20"))
rate <- c(0.25, 0.25, 0.50, 0.50)
changedToday <- c(NA, 0, 1, 0)
RATES <- data.frame(rates.date, rate, changedToday) #mdy() converts string to date as month day year

tweets.date <- mdy(c("01/02/20", "01/10/20"))
text <- c("Tweet 1", "tweet 2")
TWEETS <- data.frame(tweets.date, text)


for (i in c(1:nrow(TWEETS))) {
  TWEETS$changedInLast7[i] = any(filter(RATES, TWEETS$tweets.date[i] - days(7) < RATES$rates.date & RATES$rates.date <= TWEETS$tweets.date[i])$changedToday==1)
}

**RATES**
rates.date    rate  changedToday
1/1/20        0.25  NA
1/2/20        0.25  0
1/3/20        0.50  1 # 1 since it is different from yesterday
1/4/20        0.50  0

**TWEETS**
tweets.date   text
1/2/20        "tweet 1"
1/10/20       "tweet 2"

**GOAL**
*TWEETS*
tweets.date   text       changeInLast7
1/2/20        "tweet 1"  FALSE
1/10/20       "tweet 2"  TRUE
```

Comment: updated with input tables and goal output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacement of `for` loop can be done with `sapply` :

```
TWEETS$changedInLast7 <- sapply(TWEETS$tweets.date, function(x)
                         any(with(RATES, (x - 7) <= rates.date & 
                         rates.date <= x & changedToday == 1), na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

A `tidyverse` way would be :

```
library(dplyr)

tidyr::crossing(TWEETS, RATES) %>%
    group_by(tweets.date, text) %>%
    summarise(changeInLast7 = any(between(rates.date, first(tweets.date) - 7, 
                          first(tweets.date)) & changedToday == 1, na.rm = TRUE))


# tweets.date   text    changeInLast7
#  <date>      <fct>   <lgl>        
#1 2020-01-02  Tweet 1 FALSE        
#2 2020-01-10  tweet 2 TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
TWEETS$changedInLast7 <- unlist(lapply(TWEETS$tweets.date, function(x)
                     any(with(RATES, (x - 7) <= rates.date & 
                     rates.date <= x & changedToday == 1), na.rm = TRUE)))
```